Cannot run program "docker-credential-desktop": error=2, No such file or directory
I am using MAC OS. I am getting following error, while running mvn clean package docker:build
Error getting the credentials for localhost:8082 from the configured credential helper[m: Failed to start 'docker-credential-desktop get' : Cannot run program "docker-credential-desktop": error=2, No such file or directory
Error getting the credentials for localhost:8082 from the configured credential helper
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to start 'docker-credential-desktop get' : Cannot run program "docker-credential-desktop": error=2, No such file or directory at
My .docker/config.json looks like following
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {},
        "localhost:8082": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "experimental": "disabled",
    "currentContext": "desktop-linux",
    "plugins": {
        "-x-cli-hints": {
            "enabled": "true"
        },
        "debug": {
            "hooks": "exec"
        },
        "scout": {
            "hooks": "pull,buildx build"
        }
    },
    "features": {
        "hooks": "true"
    }
}

I am using io.fabric8 plugin with following configuration
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin
    </artifactId>
    <version>0.44.0
    </version>
    <configuration>
        <pullRegistry>localhost:8082
        </pullRegistry>
        <pushRegistry>localhost:8083/apbcr/snapshots
        </pushRegistry>
        <containerNamePattern>%n-%i
        </containerNamePattern>
        <verbose>true
        </verbose>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>%g/%a
                </name>
                <alias>dockerfile
                </alias>
                <build>
                    <!-- filter>@
                    </filter-->
                    <contextDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker
                    </contextDir>
                    <assembly>
                        <descriptorRef>artifact
                        </descriptorRef>
                    </assembly>
                    <dockerFile>Dockerfile
                    </dockerFile>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>%v
                        </tag>
                    </tags>
                </build>
                <run>
                    <ports>
                        <port>8080:8080
                        </port>
                    </ports>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
        <authConfig>
            <push>
                <username>admin
                </username>
                <password>admin
                </password>
            </push>
        </authConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

What am I doing wrong?

Only change required is in .docker/config.json and that is removal of following in .docker/config.json
"credsStore": "desktop"

